# Al intentar consumir mi API de spring-boot con JasperReport, aparece el error 15863 Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: null

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

Cuando intento consumir mi API me da el siguiente error:

> 2022-07-12 21:43:11.696 ERROR 15863 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] n.s.j.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser     : Error while loading available fonts
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException:  javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:159) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.getInstance(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:134) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.ensureFontExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:80) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.FontExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(FontExtensionsRegistry.java:57) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.getExtensions(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:134) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.(JRStyledTextParser.java:87) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.(JRBaseFiller.java:114) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.(JRVerticalFiller.java:82) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:251) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:272) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:156) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:145) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:758) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:1074) [jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> at server.modules.da.mantenimiento.programaciones.services.ProgramacionService.generateReport(ProgramacionService.java:291) [main/:na]
> at server.modules.da.mantenimiento.programaciones.controllers.ProgramacionController.reporteLocal(ProgramacionController.java:130) [main/:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_333]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at server.config.filter.ServerFilterHeaders.doFilter(ServerFilterHeaders.java:51) [main/:na]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) [spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [na:1.8.0_333]

> **Caused by:** javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: null
> at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(JXDocumentBuilderFactory.java:380) ~[xmlparserv2-21.3.0.0.jar:21.0.0.0.0]
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:152) ~[jasperreports-6.19.1.jar:6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c]
> ... 60 common frames omitted

Actualmente a mi archivo `build.gradle` lo tengo de esta manera:

```
// Jasper

    implementation group: 'net.sf.jasperreports', name: 'jasperreports', version: '6.19.1'

    compileOnly group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-collections4', version: '4.2'
    
compileOnly group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '2.1.7'
    
implementation 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports-fonts:6.19.1'
    
implementation 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.4.01'
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser?

Comment: ¿Cuáles fuentes usas en tu reporte?

Comment: Según se indica en el reporte es Arial

Comment: ¿En cuál sistema operativo esta Tomcat?

Comment: En oracle linux

Comment: Normalmente Linux no incluye la fuente Arial de forma predeterminada. O cambias a una fuente mas común (ej. SansSerif), o instalas la fuente en el sistema operativo, o [exporta](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v640/working-font-extensions) la fuente con la herramienta de diseño  (iReport/Jaspersoft Studio/Plugin) y agrega el Jar exportado a tu aplicación.

Comment: Ah genial, voy a revisar eso y confirmo.